# Kernel Test: How can I get an overridden config value from settings.php

Tags: 8, testing

In my settings.php file i have a custom configuration that is changed on a per site basis, e.g. `$config['brand_id'] = 1`

I have a function that will fetch that value, and I am trying to setup a kernel test for it. When I try to fetch the config, it returns null.
When I try to setup the config and save it, I get the error `Missing namespace in Config object name 'brand_id'`, which I believe is because there is no `.` in the name (e.g. `brand.id`). If i add that it then tries to look for a schema to validate against, which I don't have as it is just in the settings file.

Is there a way to fetch or set this value in the test, or am I forced to setup a config yaml file just to make this testable?

Comment: I suspect that you may not be able to do this in a kernel test, and that you may need a full functional test to be able to retrieve overridden values. Only a suspicion though, I may be entirely wrong.